# What does the word "indeed" mean in math?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, terminology

The word "indeed" is often used in proofs, usually to begin a sentence.

What is the meaning and correct usage?

I've usually seen it used in this form

> [Assertion of $X$ without proof].  Indeed, [proof of $X$].

Is this interpretation correct?

---

## Update

This question asks a well defined question about a term commonly used in proofs.  I've edited the question to provide what I view as the meaning of the term, as used in proofs.  Or the answer may (or may not) be "the term has no special meaning, it's just a 'verbal tic'."  But that itself is useful information for someone reading a proof and wanting to know what the term means.  As witnessed by the questions in the *Related* sidebar, math.SE is a useful resource when it provides the meaning of words like "only", "naive", "imply" or other words that are common in both daily usage and proofs.

The question is tagged `terminology` and `soft-question`, and meets those criteria.

Comment: Essentially nothing. I usually read it as "As an example of or further evidence for the behavior I just mentioned..."

Comment: It's not a technical term, it's just English.  The [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=indeed) says "Used in a clause which confirms and amplifies a previous statement: In point of fact, as a matter of fact."

Comment: Besides what @walkar said, another common way of using "indeed" in mathematical writing is as a transition to a more precise result or a logically stronger result. For example: For integers, the square of a non-multiple of $3$ is a non-multiple of $3.$ Indeed, the square of a non-multiple of $3$ is always one more than a multiple of $3.$